# Retaining view orientation

Tags: android, layout, view

I have an actoivity that implements the methods of SurfaceHolder and to work with camera.
In the main layout, which is a LinearLayout, I inserted another LinearLayout to act as an overlay and I setted the orientation to Landscape.

```
View overlayView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cameraoverlay, null);
    this.addContentView(overlayView,
            new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Because of this, the overlay, obviously, rotates too. And this is the problem. In the case of a dynamic view, how can I maintain the previously orientation of the overlay view?

Thanks for replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the activity orientation to landscape in the android manifest.

```
<activity android:name=".activity.NewSearchBrowserActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.FullScreen" android:screenOrientation="landscape"></activity>
```

this override any later orientation on the activity and it´s inner views.

Comment: Franco, this is the same to setRequestedOrientation. The main linear layout is corrected. My problem is related to the overlay layout loaded dynamically. I don't know if this helps but I'm using a SurfaceView to show the camera. Works fine. Like I said, the only problem is the overlayLayout.

Comment: i dont understand why, if you specify the 'landscape' orientation in the activity then the layout changes? In example i'm doing a AR app, i have the SurfaceView inside a FrameLayout, and the overlays layouts like SurfaceView siblings, (FrameLayout child)... I dont want to anything rotates and for that i set the activity orientation to landscape in the manifest. So i ask you again (cause maybe i dont understand the question). You want that SurfaceView and the layouts maintain always the same orientation?

Comment: Layout changes in the same way when I use setRequestedOrientation. The problem occurs in this point:
 inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
      View overlayView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cameraoverlay, null);
      this.addContentView(overlayView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
And then, my layout is rotated 90 degrees clockwise. I understand why. The only problem is to maintain it.
What I really want to know is to maintain the overlay that is inserted in this point.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: i understand better now, i don't ever experiment this and i do the same you do, instead my main layout is a RelativeLayout and has an only child at init: a FrameLayout. Later on activity creation i add the SurfaceView to the FrameLayout and the other overlays (Radar, stuff, etc) i add to the RelativeLayout and works fine. I don't know if adding the inflated views to the activity itself (with addContentView) overrides the previous orientation setted)

Comment: Ok Franco, but what you suggest? Even my Toast messages appears wrong. Instead they appear horizontally, they appear vertically. For me it's really strange.

Comment: for me too, did you trying to use a RelativeLayout as main layout and use that view to addView instead of using addContentView into the activity?

Comment: Honesty, I don't know what I can do now. I'll try other things.

Comment: No, but I found the solution. In the Camera.Parameters class there are a method called setRotation. I passed 90 and it works. I've tried to rotate all the other view, but any of these tries have worked. Just the last one. Thanks very much for your replies. P.S: If you've found some code, please send me the link.

Comment: i never imagine that the trouble comes from that side, good luck!